# How to iterate through out an array with a value path as reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, ecmascript-6

I don't really know how to express what I want, but I'll try.

So, I have an `object` with an `array` inside with the name of `recipes`, that I receive from my `API`, and a `valuePath` which is an `object`:

**Object**

```
{
  recipes: [
    {
      test: {
        items: [
          {
            type: 'test1',
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**ValuePath**

```
{
  "allRecipes": {
    "array": "recipes",
    "values": {
      "allTypes": {
        "array": "test",
        "values": {
          "type": "type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Briefly what I have to do, is iterate over the `array recipes` through out the `valuePath`, dynamically, because the `array` and the `values` can change. I don't really know how to explain it better and how to iterate thought deeply nested `objects/array's` having a `valuePath` as a reference to find the `values`.

What I've tried so far...

```
 export const test = (object, valuePath) => {
  for (const prop in valuePath) {
    object = object[valuePath[prop].array]; // find the array

    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
      object.forEach(objRef => {
        console.log('valueRef', objRef);
      });
    }

    console.log('props->', valuePath[prop].values); // find the values
  }
};
```

I think i need a recursion, but have no clue how to do one.

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: @Shubh in this case I want to get type `test1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem, this could be an implementation...
If you run it with your data and path, it will return `test1`.

```js
// INPUTS
const data = {
  recipes: [
    {
      test: {
        items: [
          {
            type: 'test1',
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

const path = {
  "allRecipes": {
    "array": "recipes",
    "values": {
      "allTypes": {
        "array": "test",
        "values": {
          "type": "type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



// this is just an helper method for arrays...
Array.prototype.first = function () { return this[0] }


// this is an helper function that tells us whether
// a path object is still traversable.
// from what I understood, if it contains an `array` property
// we should follow it...
const isTraversable = path => !!path.array


// this is the actual implementation of the algorithm
const traverse = (data, path) => {
  const nextPath = Object.values(path).first()
  
  if ( isTraversable(nextPath) ) {
    const array = data[nextPath.array]

    // I noticed that at a certain point in the data object,
    // we need to traverse an array, and in another it is an
    // object with an `items` property.
    // this next lines helps determine how go down
    const nextData = Array.isArray(array) ? array.first() : array.items

    // we recurse on the traversed data and path
    return traverse(nextData, nextPath.values)
  }

  return data.first()[path.type]
}

console.log(traverse(data, path))
```

Comment: I liked the code, it's almost what I want... but by any chance, it'll be possible if `type` in `return data.first()[path.type]` was dynamic? Because in `path object`, if I change `"values": {
          "type": "type"
        }` to `"values": {
          "quantity": "quantity"
        }` the following code becomes invalid... i'll have to change `data.first()[path.type]` to `data.first()[path.quantity]`, and i want it dynamic to not have to do this process...

Comment: Ok, I did it... just had to change `return data.first()[path.type]` to `return data.first()[path[nextPath]]`, thank you so much!!

Comment: If is not asking to much @0xc14m1z, if I want more than 1 value like `"values": {
          "type": "type", "quantity": "quantity
        }` how can i do it??

Comment: Not sure I understood. What should happen if you have more than one values? What type of value do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I hope it will help you..

```
let obj = {
  recipes: [
    {
      test: {
        items: [
          {
            type: 'test1',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};

obj.recipes.forEach(test => {
  test.test.items.forEach(items => {
    console.log(items.type);
  });
});
```

Comment: The logic is there, but the second `test` in `test.test` has to be dynamic, because it can be another name, like `cars` ou something like that. Same as `type`... that's why I have the `valuePath` as a reference... It has to be whatever name i have in the `valuePath`